# Azure Runbook script can't login with system assigned identity

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I'm trying to setup a Powershell Runbook to access Azure resources.

I'm following instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation).

I've assigned a system identity to the Automation account, the the sample script simply doesn't work.

```
# Sign in to your Azure subscription
$sub = Get-AzSubscription -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(-not($sub))
{
     Connect-AzAccount
}
```

Output:

```
Run Connect-AzAccount to login.
Port 8400 is taken with exception 'A socket operation encountered a dead network'; trying to connect to the next port.
Port 8401 is taken with exception 'A socket operation encountered a dead network'; trying to connect to the next port.
<snip>
Port 8998 is taken with exception 'A socket operation encountered a dead network'; trying to connect to the next port.
Port 8999 is taken with exception 'A socket operation encountered a dead network'; trying to connect to the next port.
Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'Cannot find an open port.'
Cannot find an open port.
```

I tried adding Contributor and Owner role to the identity, and that didn't help.
I'm not sure what I'm missing, help?

I am using terraform to stand up the infrastructure, so it's possible I have a setting out of whack that terraform is setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet of code you have used is for authentication to enable the identity.

The snippet of code further down that page is what you need to use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation#authenticate-access-with-system-assigned-managed-identity

You'll notice it utilises `Connect-AzAccount -Identity` instead.

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process

# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

# set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

Comment: Duh, the error message lead me down all the wrong paths, and I should have just read more of the page.